# ruby on rails not working correctly in windows XP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

I downloaded RoR ans installed in on my Windows XP, but anyhow its not working. I am totally new to thie RoR. Please check my following screenshots --

1)This is what i did initially -
[image]

2)Started rails server but it wont.

[image]

3)Even rails version command is not working.

[image]

4)This is what creating in my aap2 folder :(

[image]

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

**NOTE**  -- I installed RoR via `rails-installer`.exe

Installer info --

[image]

Comment: What version of Rails do you think you're installing? You're creating a bunch of new Rails apps. And posting images instead of text :(

Comment: @DaveNewton please check my installer info screenshot -- Complete Rails Installer contains Ruby 1.9 , Rails 2.3 , SQLite3 , FxRuby 1.6 and some other Important Gems CompleteRailsInstaller.

Comment: Rails 2.3 is rather old. Suggest you try a newer version. Rails 3.2 is current now.

Comment: You're installing old Rails, and trying to use it like new Rails. And posting images instead of text :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've installed Rails 2.3 but you're expecting it to work like Rails 3.

The correct syntax for Rails 2.3 is:

```
rails myproject
```

The correct syntax for Rails 3.x is:

```
rails new myproject
```

For both, you probably want to check the version with:

```
rails -v
```

Rails 2.3 is no longer actively supported so you should not be creating new projects with it.

Comment: and how do i start rails server then ?

Comment: Best would be for you to reinstall with railsinstaller from http://railsinstaller.org; it will set you up with the current versions and guide you step by step through the installation and usage.